# why doesn't the following use of rowcolor work in a table?

Tags: tables, color

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}

\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\rowcolor[amber]{0.9} xx
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get an error about the color model of amber not being defined. I looked up color models in here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#Color_Models and it seems like I define it correctly.

Comment: `\rowcolor[amber]`  would reference a colour _model_ called amber instead of the usual models such as rgb or cmyk. You want to reference the color you have defined so `\rowcolor{amber}`

Comment: And if you only want to use 90 percent amber, you can use `\rowcolor{amber!90}` (which will mix 90% amber with 10% white).